# CSS Counters: doesn't reset if there is a wrapper outside OL

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I tried to create a custom Ordered List (`OL`) using "**CSS Counters**" taking as example [this Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters).

I need to slightly modify it, wrapping last OL in a DIV containter named `.foo`, as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbmg52sz/1/).

```
<div id='foo'>
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>          <!-- 1     -->
      <li>item</li>          <!-- 2     -->
    </ol>
</div>

ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

Adding wrapper, counter does not reset anymore and numbers continue from 4.1 and 4.2. Why? How to reset new counter even if is wrapped inside a container? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add counter reset to the div and assign a new value to the wrapped ol.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbmg52sz/3/

```
ol{
  counter-reset: sectionA;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: sectionA;
  content: counters(sectionA,".") " ";
}

div{
    counter-reset: sectionA;
}

div > ol{
    counter-reset: sectionB;
}

div > ol > li{
    counter-increment: sectionB;
    content: counters(sectionB,".") " ";
}
```

Comment: mhmmm I wouldn't like to create 2 separated counter lists, because if I change wrapper (is an editorial site), this solution is too much fine tuned to this specific case. I don't understand why two contigous OL reset their own counter and if I separate them with a wrapper, reset will not run.